# apt-get really slow but no internet problems

Tags: apt, updates, internet

I'm running into an issue where running `apt-get update` and `apt-get install` are really slow. It's relatively quick (~600 KB/s) for the first 5 seconds but then slows down to 4 KB/s or less. I don't have any internet problems, though. Here's the result of a speed test:

[image: speed test]

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` file is pointing to http://us.archive.ubuntu.com. I thought maybe it was a problem with the mirror, but downloading a file from http://us.archive.ubuntu.com is fast:

```
$ wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Contents-amd64.gz
--2015-08-17 14:46:53--  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Contents-amd64.gz
Resolving us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.91.14, 91.189.91.15, 91.189.91.13, ...
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.14|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 14723021 (14M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘Contents-amd64.gz’

100%[==========================================================================================================================================================>] 14,723,021   832KB/s   in 17s    

2015-08-17 14:47:10 (845 KB/s) - ‘Contents-amd64.gz’ saved [14723021/14723021]
```

What could be going on here?

EDIT: For what it's worth, I'm running Ubuntu in a VirtualBox VM.

Comment: A mirror may be slow, change to another.

Comment: I tried switching the mirror a couple times, but us.archive.ubuntu.com was still the fastest. Also, since using `wget` was fast, I don't think it's related to the mirror.

Comment: You're running inside a VM, using the virtual ethernet interface to talk to the VM's host system, which will do something with your traffic. Have you discussed this problem with your VM provider? Try `tracepath slashdot.org`

Comment: do you have a proxy involved anywhere? I have the same problems at work, sometimes down to 1KB/s :(

Answer (score -1):

I am afraid it might not be your computer, but your ISP. They are probably throttling your connection when it notices that you are downloading a file. I have heard some ISP's do that to prevent piracy and downloading torrents (and to reduce their bandwidth cost), but this forum isn't about this so I recommend talking with your ISP and explaining to them that you are trying to get packages for your operating system and that you're not downloading movies or something.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a guess, not an answer. How can @mrdziuban detect throttling?

Comment: I already gave my "guess" on how to find out